# Syntax error Javascript foreach

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok.. Im a Java developer (new). And Im trying to figure out Javascript. And React, thats why I have "this.props", its coming from the reducer.. Anyway

I have an object with id.
And a account array with id, and names.
I just want to compare each account array id with the object id and return the account name. Simple right? Obviously not for me. I get a syntax error and I really dont know what Im doing wrong...

```
getName = object => {
const objectId = object.id;

const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => (
            if (account.id === objectId)
                return this.account.name;

        )
    )
        return name;
    }
```

EDIT: Thank you everyone! Ive change the "()" to "{}" and this.account.name to account.name. And it works! I did not see that mistake

Comment: "I get a syntax error" — And what does that syntax error say?

Comment: The arrow function syntax must be: params => { } not params => ()

Comment: Are you using some library that has `foreach` function? If not you need to change to `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

You are using parenthesis instead of braces in the callback function passed to the `foreach`

```
getName = object => {
const objectId = object.id;

const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => {
            if (account.id === objectId)
                return this.account.name;

        }
    )
        return name;
    }
```

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it solve the problem?

Comment: I've upvoted you, f-CJ. Why would anyone downvote your answer.

Comment: @f-CJ — You had plenty of time to edit it *before* you decided it was ready enough to click "Post Your Answer".

Comment: Quentin he tried to help in minimal time. I've added an explanation of the change and posted a second after him due to this.

Comment: Thank you. Because I first answered with just the code keeping in mind to add some text as a guide afterwards. But i was down voted the second I posted the answer.

Comment: Try waiting until you've written a good answer before posting it then. If you post a bad answer with the intention of improving it later and get downvoted while it is bad, then that's on you.

Comment: Some users simply have no idea about sportsmanship, no matter their reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

It was just a little mistake. Whenever you are executing a block of code it is supposed to be in {}, not (). Just like in java or most programming languages in general.

```
getName = object => {
const objectId = object.id;

const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => {
            if (account.id === objectId)
                return this.account.name;
        }
    )
        return name;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
return this.account.name;
```

To

```
return account.name;
```

As,

```
const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => {
        if (account.id === objectId)
            return account.name;
})
```

As this is pointing to props and not account. As you have account object in your parameters of forEach you can directly access name.

Answer (score 0):

Its a syntax error. Consider using an editor/IDE that catches such mistakes. Have commented what needs to be changed in your code:

```
  getName = object => {
  const objectId = object.id;

  const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => ( // should be {
    if (account.id === objectId)
    return this.account.name;
  ) // should be }
  )
  return name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `forEach` you pass a function and the function body requires curly brackets `{}`, not parentheses `()`. You are doing everything fine, the only problem are the parentheses. Your code should look like this:

```
const name = this.props.accounts.foreach(account => {
    if (account.id === objectId)
      return account.name;
  })
```

P.S.: you can use `filter` also instead of `forEach`.